# How do i give Ratings objective c?

Tags: objective-c

How it can be Possible in View Using third party Library in this image:-

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use third party libraries

[StarRatingView](https://github.com/henghonglee/StarRatingView)

[HCSStarRatingView](https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView)

[ASStarRatingView](https://github.com/yanguango/ASStarRatingView)

also read tutorial

[star rating view](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view)